# TYPO3 - Link to external URL redirect

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 v6.2 and inside the footer I have links to my social networks :

[image]

As you can see, it is "Link to external URL".

Problem: TYPO3 creates new URL [www.mycompany.com/twitter](http://www.mycompany.com/twitter) and then redirects to [www.twitter.com/mycompany](http://www.twitter.com/mycompany) with a 303. How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 6.2 you need to do the immediate rendering in the menu by yourself:
For each page with type "external URL" (`doktype == 3`) you need to do a special handling.

```
NO {
    :
    your default configuration
    :
    // special handling for 'external URL' 
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    doNotLinkIt.if {
        equals.field = doktype
        value = 3
    }
    stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
    stdWrap.cObject {
        if {
            equals.field = doktype
            value = 3
        }
        field = navtitle // title
        typolink {
            parameter.field = url
            extTarget.field = target
        }
    }
}
```

If you also want special handling for shortcuts you better use a `CASE` object with `key.field = doktype`

```
NO {
    :
    std handling (wrap)
    : 

    // don't do the std link:
    doNotLinkIt = 1
    // but link it yourself:
    stdWrap.cObject = CASE
    stdWrap.cObject {
        key.field = doktype

        // normal pages:      
        default = TEXT
        default {
            field = navtitle // title
            typolink.parameter.field = uid
        }

        // shortcut
        4 < .default
        4.typolink.parameter.field = shortcut

        // external url
        3 < .default
        3.typolink.parameter.field = url
        3.typolink.extTarget.field = target
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get a probem when using your 2nd solution : I have to store a COA object in the "default" (with <i>) ... but the "default" of "stdWrap.cObject = CASE" only accepts TEXT .. any solution ?

Comment: for the cases any TYPO3 object should be possible. Note that aside to the content also the object type is copied to the other cases. if you only need an additional tag around the value you can use a wrap. Since 6.2 everything should have stdWrap properties.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour has changed in TYPO3 7: [Breaking: #62812 - Resolve URLs to “Link to external URL”-pages directly](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.6/Breaking-62812-ResolveMenuUrlsToLinkToExternalPagesDirectly.html)

> The behaviour of pages with the type “Link to External URL” has changed for menus. Those pages link now directly to the provided url instead of linking the internal page with a redirect afterwards.

I assume that is what was intended in the question.